# Nav bar button sometimes generates a .htm download in Firefox with a randomly generated file name each time, e.g. "Kp_YtxxC"?

Tags: html, css, button, nav

Clicking on a button in my nav bar on my website https://sookim1.github.io is sometimes generating a download dialog box of file type .htm with what seems to be a randomized filed name. The issue is occurring in Firefox frequently. I have not seen the issue occur in Edge or Chrome, and I don't know what is triggering it. I was able to recreate the issue on Windows 10 and 11, desktop, and laptop. It usually occurs clicking on a button multiple times or spam clicking in the nav area.

[Example image of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21aoN.png)

HTML & CSS files: https://drive.google.com/drive/u/5/folders/1VjowILOkwZVCBFThXcLgAuZcukO-gEJ1

Video of the issue: https://youtu.be/1wsT60dsZMQ

Code:

```css
/*creates the menu bar*/

.menulist {
  z-index: 2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  text-align: center;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  background-color: #2e2c27;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-top-width: 4px;
  border-bottom-width: 4px;
  border-color: antiquewhite;
  /*border-style: dotted;
        border-width: 5px;
        border-color: turquoise;*/
}

.menulist ul {
  overflow: visible;
}

.navbtn a {
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.menulist a {
  /*text-transform: capitalize;*/
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  /*margin-bottom: 10.1em;*/
  font-family: "Arial", "Calibri", sans-serif;
  font-size: 125%;
}

.menulist a:link,
.menulist a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.menulist a.active {
  /* background-color: #ccded8; */
  color: white;
  border-bottom: .1em solid #ccded8;
}

.menulist input[type=search] {
  display: inline-block;
}

.menulist button {
  border-radius: 10%;
}

.menulist button:active {
  animation-name: button-hover;
  animation-duration: 100ms;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes button-hover {
  50% {
    font-style: italic;
    transform: scale(1.08);
  }
  100% {
    font-style: italic;
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
}

.menulist li:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menulist li:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menulist li:active {
  text-decoration: none;
}


/*The buttons and drop down menus on the menu bar*/

.dropdown {
  display: inline;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.navbtn {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 17px;
  height: 75.5px;
}

.dropdown .navbtn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbtn a {
  /*border: solid;
        border-width: 4px;
        border-color: blue;*/
}

.navbtn a:hover {
  animation-name: nav-hover;
  animation-duration: 220ms;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.dropdown:hover .navbtn {
  /*background-color: #00134d;*/
  transition: .2s;
  border-radius: 1px;
  /*transition: 240ms;*/
}

@keyframes nav-hover {
  100% {
    background-color: burlywood;
  }
}

.dropdown-content {
  opacity: .995;
  border-radius: 2px;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: .3%;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: inherit;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 2;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.noselect {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  /* iOS Safari */
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  /* Safari */
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  /* Konqueror HTML */
  -moz-user-select: none;
  /* Old versions of Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none;
  /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
  user-select: none;
  /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                  supported by Chrome, Edge, Opera and Firefox */
}
```

```html
<ul class="menulist">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="navbtn" draggable="false" ondragstart="return false;">
      <a class="active noselect" href="index.html" draggable="false" ondragstart="return false;">About</a>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="index.html#aboutme" class="noselect" draggable="false" ondragstart="return false;">Me</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</ul>
```

---

I do not have the "libredirect" addon installed or previously installed.

https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/tzredg/what_are_these_random_htm_files_that_firefox/

Comment: Did you recreate using the same Firefox profile (with the same extensions)? Maybe try with a different profile (or none). I wasn't able to reproduce.

Comment: @isherwood I reproduced the issue on a new profile with no extensions/etc.